# Is the IUSR Account a Service Account?

Tags: windows, iis

In Windows, there is a built-in account called IUSR. IIS uses this account as the default account for Anonymous Authentication.

Anyway, my question is:
is this IUSR account a service account?

In general, how can you tell if a windows account is a service account?

The reason I ask this is that there is a rule in windows for determining if an account is allowed to write to the event log. According to this rule, a service account is allowed to write to the event log. The rule is described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/fail-write-event-log

Comment: `is this IUSR account a service account?' No. The IUSR account does not logon as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows OS has special identity groups.
*SERVICE* is one of them. So allowing or denying some permissions or rights to the *SERVICE* group will impact any process running as a service, regardless the user account it is run under (that user account permissions also applies though)

> Service
>
> This identity group includes all security principals that are signed in as a service. This identity grants access to processes that Windows Server services are running. Membership is controlled by the operating system

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-special-identities-groups